# Computer vision techniques to measure a distance in the same object?

Tags: python, filter, deep-learning, computer-vision

I would like to calculate the length of the label of a bottle of coke using computer vision techniques?

[e.g. find size of label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwtUw.png)

I tried to use some filters (sobel, canny, ...) to better highlight the label. Now I would like to try to determine the length. Do any of you know techniques to find it?

For now I have only found these references:

- https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/
- https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/04/measuring-distance-between-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Do you mean length in the image or in the real world?

Comment: In the real world
Thank you for the reply

Comment: Generally speaking, you need more data in order to determine the real world length, something that will help you determine the scale (a pair of images with their relative locations / some element in the bottle which you already know its size). It maybe worth to explain what data are you using, how is it acquired, etc.

Comment: I see! For now I don't have a homogeneous image dataset yet. I thought I'd start from the image I shared to write a first python script to determine the length of the label. For example in this case the label put in full measures 210 x 50 mm (reference: https://colnect.com/it/drink_labels/drink_label/82233-Coca-Cola-Coca-Cola_HBC_Italia_SRL-Italia)